# Click on object triggers a separate link on the same page

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap

Hi I am using the bootstrap-tab.js (below) [to change tabs](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/javascript.html#tabs) and I would like to activate one of the tabs using a separate link on the page. I can quite easily access the second tabs content by linking to "#tab2" but the problem is that the tab system doesn't reflect the change. So my Tab1 is active while Tab2 content is displayed, if that makes sense.

I suspect the the easiest way to do this (given the js) is to trigger the link click from the actual tab using js. Any idea how to achieve this?

```
!function ($) {

  "use strict"; // jshint ;_;


 /* TAB CLASS DEFINITION
  * ==================== */

  var Tab = function (element) {
    this.element = $(element)
  }

  Tab.prototype = {

    constructor: Tab

  , show: function () {
      var $this = this.element
        , $ul = $this.closest('ul:not(.dropdown-menu)')
        , selector = $this.attr('data-target')
        , previous
        , $target
        , e

      if (!selector) {
        selector = $this.attr('href')
        selector = selector && selector.replace(/.*(?=#[^\s]*$)/, '') //strip for ie7
      }

      if ( $this.parent('li').hasClass('active') ) return

      previous = $ul.find('.active a').last()[0]

      e = $.Event('show', {
        relatedTarget: previous
      })

      $this.trigger(e)

      if (e.isDefaultPrevented()) return

      $target = $(selector)

      this.activate($this.parent('li'), $ul)
      this.activate($target, $target.parent(), function () {
        $this.trigger({
          type: 'shown'
        , relatedTarget: previous
        })
      })
    }

  , activate: function ( element, container, callback) {
      var $active = container.find('> .active')
        , transition = callback
            && $.support.transition
            && $active.hasClass('fade')

      function next() {
        $active
          .removeClass('active')
          .find('> .dropdown-menu > .active')
          .removeClass('active')

        element.addClass('active')

        if (transition) {
          element[0].offsetWidth // reflow for transition
          element.addClass('in')
        } else {
          element.removeClass('fade')
        }

        if ( element.parent('.dropdown-menu') ) {
          element.closest('li.dropdown').addClass('active')
        }

        callback && callback()
      }

      transition ?
        $active.one($.support.transition.end, next) :
        next()

      $active.removeClass('in')
    }
  }


 /* TAB PLUGIN DEFINITION
  * ===================== */

  $.fn.tab = function ( option ) {
    return this.each(function () {
      var $this = $(this)
        , data = $this.data('tab')
      if (!data) $this.data('tab', (data = new Tab(this)))
      if (typeof option == 'string') data[option]()
    })
  }

  $.fn.tab.Constructor = Tab


 /* TAB DATA-API
  * ============ */

  $(function () {
    $('body').on('click.tab.data-api', '[data-toggle="tab"], [data-toggle="pill"]', function (e) {
      e.preventDefault()
      $(this).tab

('show')
    })
  })

}(window.jQuery);
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, sorry about this I figured it out.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#scoretab').click(function (e) {
      $('#myTab a[href="#tab2"]').tab('show');
    })
});
```

Comment: scoretab is just the id for the link that I wanted to trigger the tab change.